# How can you make a div be the height of the img OR text within it?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm a little stuck. I have the following code (I commented some out), and it's not working as expected.

Currently, the height of the div of class="article" only extends as far as the div of class="info" extends. However, I want it to extend as far as the div of class="info" OR the image extend. In other words, I want the div of class=article to have a height of whichever is taller: the image or the div of class="info".

```
<div class="article" style="padding-bottom:30px">
      <img src="img.jpg" style="height:70px;width:70px;border-radius:50%;margin-right:10px" align="left">
      <div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lacus lacinia est tempus. </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if that is a super confusing explanation...let me know if more clarification is needed.

Thank you!

Comment: align=left is obsolete and it is actually acting like float:left; ... I guess you need to clear your floatting element

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `align` attribute as it's deprecated in HTML5. You can `float` the image instead, then apply some sort of clearfix. Added a clearfix class that you can reuse on any element that has floated children.

```css
.article {
  background: #eee;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="article clearfix" style="padding-bottom:30px">
  <img src="img.jpg" style="height:70px;width:70px;border-radius:50%;margin-right:10px;float:left;">
  <div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lacus lacinia est tempus. </div>
</div>
```